# Diffrence between Wordpress themes and HTML, CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

This might be a stupid question, but I really cant understand the diffrence between creating websites with Wordpress or seperately with HTML,CSS. I see incredible Designed Wordpress templates. 
So I cant understand are these wordpress templates added to an already created website or when you use wordpress there is no need to write code with html..? I am little confused ..

Answer (score 1):

When using PHP, One of the main problems, if not the most important one, is that pages (including HTML, CSS, JS) are rendered inline PHP programs, which makes the pages fragmented and probably separated into different PHP programs, and makes developing themes somehow harder. That's why templates are widely used in modern frameworks like Django, Ruby on Rails.

Nevertheless, programming in PHP is much easier with the help of MVC frameworks and/or CMS systems. In CMS systems like Wordpress, the HTML parts and CSS parts (and JS parts) inline PHP programs are collected and put in a number of files, and the collection of these files are called Themes. So you can modify the themes or replace them, without touching the PHP code. Files in the themes are literally HTML/CSS/JS, if I'm not getting it wrong, and you can use them as a whole, or modify them according to the rules of Wordpress.

And yes you can write pages without the help of CMS systems like Wordpress, but CMS systems simplify the management and modification of pages, help you to reuse codes in one page or in different pages, and other features of CMS systems may also apply. You should check the feature list to see if there's anything you need and consider to prefer Wordpress over HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: Correct. Also I would like to add that there are other options too. Java EE, which includes diffrent techniques, also will allow you to create content with the MVC pattern.Java EE, as well as Wordpress, PHP and so on, all of them will ultimatly use HTML and CSS to create the `view` content.